# By using React framer motion "drag and reorder" I can drag the card but does not stick to the new position. After dragging it, return to the original

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve this: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-drag-to-reorder-fc4rt?file=/src/use-position-reorder.js

Basically you can drag a card, place it somewhere in the container and reorder the card based on where you drag/put it from the original place.

The problem is that in my code, you can drag the card but not place it. I tried to change the code so many times but I can't find a way out of it. Below you will find the code where I render the component `FavouriteTreeNodeComponent` which is a **LI(List)** nested in `FavouriteTreeNodesList` a **UL(Unordered List)** :

```
// react
import { useRef, useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
// animation spring
import { animated, Transition, useSpring } from 'react-spring';
import { AnimateSharedLayout } from 'framer-motion';
// styled components
import styled from 'styled-components';
// framer motion
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { usePositionReorder } from './ReorderingModalNodes/use-position-reorder';
// icons
import { MdClose } from 'react-icons/md';
// components
import TemplateItem from './TemplateItem';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import DurationIntervalComponent from './DurationIntervalComponent';
import ContextItem from './ContextItem';
import FavouriteTreeNodeComponent from './FavouriteTreeNodeComponent';

const TimeEntryModal = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
  // STATES
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');
  const [reportingTemplates, setReportingTemplates] = useState([]);
  const [reportingContexts, setReportingContexts] = useState([]);
  // USEREF
  const modalRef = useRef();
  // ANIMATION MODAL
  const animation = useSpring({
    config: {
      duration: 250,
    },
    opacity: showModal ? 1 : 0,
    transform: showModal ? `translateY(0%)` : `translateY(-100%)`,
  });

  // CLOSING MODAL FROM BACKGROUND
  const closeModal = (e) => {
    if (modalRef.current === e.target) {
      setShowModal(false);
    }
  };
  // CLOSING MODAL WITH ESCAPE BUTTON
  const keyPress = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape' && showModal) {
        setShowModal(false);
        console.log('I pressed');
      }
    },
    [setShowModal, showModal]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
  }, [keyPress]);

  const variants = {
    hidden: {
      y: '-100vh',
    },
    visible: { y: 0, transition: { ease: 'easeInOut', duration: 1 } },
    exit: {
      y: '-100vh',
    },
  };
  // DATA
  const colorsData = [
    '#86d8bda1',
    '#eb472a83',
    '#8fcfe3ad',
    '#db8ddfb0',
    '#e8e46fc0',
    '#e1aa66b2',
  ];

  const List = [
    '3000',
    '4000',
    '5000',
    '6000',
    '7000',
    '8000',
  ];
  // FAVOURITES LIST ANIMATION
  const [updatedList, updatePosition, updateOrder] =
    usePositionReorder(List);

  // FETCHES

  useEffect(() => {
    getTemplates();
  }, []);

  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/graphql';

  const getTemplates = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: `query {
                    reportingTemplates {
                      name
                      _id
                      colorScheme
                      reportingContexts {
                        name
                        _id    
                      }
                    }
                  }`,
        }),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      const dataWithColors = data.data.reportingTemplates.map((obj, i) => ({
        ...obj,
        color: colorsData[i],
      }));
      setReportingTemplates(dataWithColors);
      setSelected(dataWithColors[0].color);
      setReportingContexts(dataWithColors[0].reportingContexts);
      console.log('data', dataWithColors);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('ERROR', err);
    }
  };

  console.log('data state', reportingTemplates);

  return (
    <Background ref={modalRef} onClick={closeModal}>
      <motion.div
        variants={variants}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="visible"
        exit="exit"
      >
        <ModalWrapper>
          <ModalContent>
            <Nav>
              <h3>New Entry Tirsdag 2. Sep </h3>
            </Nav>
            <ModalColumns>
              <ColumnOne>
                <TemplatesContainer>
                  <AnimateSharedLayout>
                    <Templates>
                      {reportingTemplates.map((template, index) => (
                        <TemplateItem
                          key={template.name}
                          color={template.color}
                          title={template.name}
                          isSelected={selected === template.color}
                          onClick={() => {
                            setReportingContexts(
                              reportingTemplates[index].reportingContexts
                            );
                            setSelected(template.color);
                          }}
                        />
                      ))}
                    </Templates>
                  </AnimateSharedLayout>
                </TemplatesContainer>
                <InformationBlock>
                  <h4>Information</h4>
                  {reportingContexts.map((context) => (
                    <ContextItem
                      key={context.name}
                      text={context.name}
                      // isSelected={selected === context.color}
                      // onClick={() => setSelected(context.color)}
                    />
                  ))}
                </InformationBlock>
                <DurationIntervalComponent />
              </ColumnOne>

              <ColumnTwo>
                <SearchBar />
                <Recent>
                  <h4>Recent</h4>
                </Recent>
                <Favourites>
                  <h4>Favourites</h4>
                  <FavouriteTreeNodesList>
                    {updatedList.map((treeNode, index) => (
                      <FavouriteTreeNodeComponent
                        key={index}
                        index={index}
                        text={treeNode}
                        updateOrder={updateOrder}
                        updatePosition={updatePosition}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </FavouriteTreeNodesList>
                </Favourites>
              </ColumnTwo>
            </ModalColumns>
          </ModalContent>
          <CloseModalButton
            aria-label="Close Modal"
            onClick={() => setShowModal((prev) => !prev)}
          />
          <Footer>
            <DeleteBlock>
              <p> Delete </p>
            </DeleteBlock>
            <CancelNSaveBlock>
              <Cancel>
                <p> Cancel </p>
              </Cancel>
              <SaveNClose>
                <p> Save and close </p>
              </SaveNClose>
              <SaveNAdd>
                <p> Save and add another </p>
              </SaveNAdd>
            </CancelNSaveBlock>
          </Footer>
        </ModalWrapper>
      </motion.div>
    </Background>
  );
};

// STYLES
const Background = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 999;
`;
const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;
const CloseModalButton = styled(MdClose)`
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
`;

// MODAL CONTENT
const ModalContent = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
`;

// NAV
const Nav = styled.div``;

const ModalColumns = styled.div`
  padding: 10px 0px;
  display: flex;
`;

// COLUMN ONE
const ColumnOne = styled.div`
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
`;
const TemplatesContainer = styled.div``;

const Templates = styled.ul`
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: initial;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const InformationBlock = styled.div`
  padding-bottom: 20px;
`;

// COLUMN TWO
const ColumnTwo = styled.div`
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
`;

const Recent = styled.div`
  background-color: #f6f6f9;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-radius: 20px;
`;

const Favourites = styled.div`

  list-style: none;
`;

const FavouriteTreeNodesList = styled.ul`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
`;

// FOOTER
const Footer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0 20px;
  bottom: 10px;
  /* text-align: center; */
  width: 100%;
`;

const DeleteBlock = styled.div`
  color: #fb423a;
`;

const CancelNSaveBlock = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
`;
// const [{name:"cancel", color func: ()=>sdasd }, "sada", "asdasd"]

const Cancel = styled.div`
  color: #02b396;
  margin-right: 40px;
`;
const SaveNClose = styled.div`
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #02b396;
  margin-right: 40px;
`;
const SaveNAdd = styled.div`
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #02b396;
`;

export default TimeEntryModal;
```

After that the list `FavouriteTreeNodeComponent` is rendered in the code below:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
// styled components
import styled from 'styled-components';
// framer motion
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { useMeasurePosition } from './ReorderingModalNodes/use-measure-position';

const FavouriteTreeNodeComponent = ({
  text,
  updateOrder,
  updatePosition,
  index,
}) => {
  const [isdragged, setIsDragged] = useState(false);
  const itemRef = useMeasurePosition((pos) => updatePosition(index, pos));

  return (
    <ListContainer>
      <motion.div
        style={{
          zIndex: isdragged ? 2 : 1,
          height: text.length * 10,
          padding: "5px",
        }}
        dragConstraints={{
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
        }}
        dragElastic={1}
        layout
        ref={itemRef}
        onDragStart={() => setIsDragged(true)}
        onDragEnd={() => setIsDragged(false)}
        animate={{
          scale: isdragged ? 1.05 : 1,
        }}
        onViewportBoxUpdate={(_, delta) => {
          isdragged && updateOrder(index, delta.y.translate);
        }}
        drag="y">{text}
      </motion.div>
    </ListContainer>
  );
};

// STYLES
const ListContainer = styled.li`
  height: auto;
  gap: 9px 0px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  list-style: none;
  div {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  }
`;

export default FavouriteTreeNodeComponent;
```

The above code is connected to the file: **useMeasurePosition** same as the original project:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function useMeasurePosition(update) {
  // We'll use a `ref` to access the DOM element that the `motion.li` produces.
  // This will allow us to measure its height and position, which will be useful to
  // decide when a dragging element should switch places with its siblings.
  const ref = useRef(null);

  // Update the measured position of the item so we can calculate when we should rearrange.
  useEffect(() => {
    update({
      height: ref.current.offsetHeight,
      top: ref.current.offsetTop,
    });
  });

  return ref;
}
```

and to the file: **usePositionReorder**:

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { clamp, distance } from 'popmotion';
import { arrayMoveImmutable as move} from 'array-move';

export function usePositionReorder(initialState) {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState(initialState);

  // We need to collect an array of height and position data for all of this component's
  // `Item` children, so we can later us that in calculations to decide when a dragging
  // `Item` should swap places with its siblings.
  const positions = useRef([]).current;
  const updatePosition = (i, offset) => (positions[i] = offset);

  // Find the ideal index for a dragging item based on its position in the array, and its
  // current drag offset. If it's different to its current index, we swap this item with that
  // sibling.
  const updateOrder = (i, dragOffset) => {
    const targetIndex = findIndex(i, dragOffset, positions);
    if (targetIndex !== i) setOrder(move(order, i, targetIndex));
  };

  return [order, updatePosition, updateOrder];
}

const buffer = 30;

export const findIndex = (i, yOffset, positions) => {
  let target = i;
  const { top, height } = positions[i];
  const bottom = top + height;

  // If moving down
  if (yOffset > 0) {
    const nextItem = positions[i + 1];
    if (nextItem === undefined) return i;

    const swapOffset =
      distance(bottom, nextItem.top + nextItem.height / 2) + buffer;
    if (yOffset > swapOffset) target = i + 1;

    // If moving up
  } else if (yOffset < 0) {
    const prevItem = positions[i - 1];
    if (prevItem === undefined) return i;

    const prevBottom = prevItem.top + prevItem.height;
    const swapOffset = distance(top, prevBottom - prevItem.height / 2) + buffer;
    if (yOffset < -swapOffset) target = i - 1;
  }

  return clamp(0, positions.length, target);
};
```